# Whenever selector is triggered trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now i have a scrolling function, that i let scroll everytime  on `textArea` and i have a lot lines where i trigger the `textArea` so automaticly i call the function scroll.

Current code;

```
var textArea = $('textArea');

if(a) {
 textArea.append(msg.a);
 scroll();
}
if(b) {
 textArea.append(msg.b);
 scroll();
}
```

So i have alot `scroll()`

Is it possible to make the call inside te variable so everytime textArea is called automaticly do the scroll, so I don't need to put it inside every function.

Comment: Put an onchange function on the textarea and that will do it each time the contents of it change

Comment: what do you mean by **"everytime textArea is called"**? `textArea` is not a method its a var

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. What do you mean with "Is it possible to make the call inside te variable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible, but it may not be advisable.  What if you have to append text to the document instead?  Do you want to call scroll on the whole page in that case?  In any case, it's very easy to extend the functionality of a jQuery function like `append()`.  Here's an example using your existing scenario:

```js
// modify jQuery functionality
(function($){
  
    // replacing old append
    var old = $.fn.append;
    $.fn.append = function()
    {
        var ret = old.apply(this, arguments);
      
        // lets keep some sanity here and check
        // if it's a textarea or not first
        if($(this).is('textarea')) {
            $(this).myScroll();
        }
        return ret;
    };
  
    // new scroll function
    $.fn.extend({
        myScroll: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).scrollTop(this.scrollHeight);
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

// meat and potatos
var textArea = $('textArea');
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        textArea.append('Some genereic text for testing purposes');   
    }, 500 * i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;"></textarea>
```

Basically what it does is it saves the old function in a variable (`old`), calls it, does your added logic, and returns the result.  I've also added a jQuery `myScroll()` function to standardize it just a little.